# Copy constructor for 2d array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor, copy

I have managed to overload the assignment operator, so I do have a workaround for this, but it would be nice to know why I couldn't get it working.

The beginning of my arr2d class looks like:

```
template <class type> class arr2d {

private:
    type* m_ptr;
    int m_nx,m_ny;

public:
    arr2d(){
            m_ptr = 0;
            m_nx = 0;
            m_ny = 0;
    }
    // Default constructor creates a null array

    arr2d(int nx, int ny):m_nx(nx),m_ny(ny){
            m_ptr = new type [nx*ny];
            if ( m_ptr==0 ){cout << "\nError allocating heap memory.\n";}
    }

//      // Copy constructor
//      arr2d(const arr2d& rhs){
//              m_ptr = new type [m_nx*m_ny];
//              for(int j=0;j<m_ny;j++){
//              for(int i=0;i<m_nx;i++){
//                     m_ptr[j*m_nx+i] = rhs.m_ptr[j*m_nx+i];
//              }
//              }
//       }
```

and so on,

You can see my attempted copy constructor commented out there.

Now in my main, I would like to call the copy constructor using for instance:

```
arr2d b=a;
```

Where the b array now has the same values as a. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Maybe not related to your problem, but it is always better to follow the Rule of Big 3.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy constructor is not assigning the array size. It should be something like

```
arr2d(const arr2d& rhs) : m_nx(rhs.m_nx), m_ny(rhs.m_ny) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to initializing `m_nx` and `m_ny` as 6502 said, you still need the template argument when declaring b. E.g.

```
arr2d<int> b = a;
```